# Using output of NDSolve in further NDSolve calculations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to use the interpolating functions found using NDSolve to solve a further differential equation where the first solutions depend on two arbitrary parameters.

As a simple example, suppose I have two coupled ODES that I can write as:

```
func[r_,u_]:=y''[x] == u*y'[x]+r^2*y[x]*x^3
sol[r_,u_]:= NDSolve[{func[r,u],y[0]==r,y'[0]==r*u},y,{x,0,50}]
func2[r_,u_]:= (z''[x]==y'[x]*r+u*y[x]*z'[x])/.sol[r,u]
sol2[r_,u_]:= NDSolve[{func2[r,u],z[0]==1,z'[0]==0},z,{x,0,50}]
```

The problem is that I get the error message when running the fourth line telling me that replacing y[x] etc. is not a good replacement rule.

In reality, my system is a horrible non-linear set f coupled ODEs with one final equation that depends on the solutions of the others. Furthermore, r and u also control the boundary conditions but I think this example suffices because I think the problems are caused by the fact that there is r and u dependence in the ODE.

I can see many posts where the output of NDSolve does not depend on any parameters, in which case it seems trivial to just define a function that does what I want e.g.

```
f1[x_]:=Evaluate[First[y[x]/.NDSolve[{y[x]''+y[x]'+x^3==0,y[0]==1,y'[0]==0},y,{x,0,50}]]]

sol=NDSolve[{z'[x]==^3*y[x]+y'[x],z[0]=0},z,{x,0,50}]
```

would work if it were not for `u`.

I am also aware that I can solve both equations simultaneously but the second equation is stiff so I would like to use a different method for it. Actually, the first set are DAE's whilst the last one is not so splitting the two would help me a lot.

I would be very grateful for any help you can give.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I actually wrote this code in by hand because my actual code is a lot more complicated and my real ODE is very long. 

Feyre, what do you mean how and I calling the function?

Comment: `sol2[r_,u_]:= ` is set delayed, so I assume you are calling it in some form of `sol2[1,2]`

Comment: ah, I see. I am calling it like that yes.

Comment: @jsaxon so how exactly are you calling it? When I run it, I just get that the system is underdetermined. For one, how come `sol2` isn't set to be dependent on the function `y`?

Comment: @Feyre ah, sorry, I made this up as I went along. I edited the post to include dependence on sol. Ideally, I would like to use y[x] as given by the solution of the first ODE for different parameters r and u so I've edited the post to include that.

Comment: Try the code in my answer.  I don't get errors on your original code either...Maybe include the exact call that gives an error.

Comment: Something's missing from the last `NDSolve` below `f1`

Comment: I guess there's no real error here.  I will vote to put on hold, unless you can say what needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I made some changes, but then realized I hadn't changed anything important. I shortened the integration to `{x, 0, 2}` to save time. The original code works with this change.  I memoized `sol` so that it's computed only once for each `{r, u}`.  You stick `First@` on `NDSolve[]` to remove a set of braces, but it's not important.

```
Clear[func, func2, sol, sol2, x, y, r, u];

func[r_, u_] := y''[x] == u*y'[x] + r^2*y[x]*x^3;
sol[r_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ] := 
 sol[r, u] = (* saves the value so that it is computed once *)
  NDSolve[{func[r, u], y[0] == r, y'[0] == r*u}, y, {x, 0, 2}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All]
func2[r_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ] := (z''[x] == y'[x]*r + u*y[x]*z'[x]) /. sol[r, u]
sol2[r_, u_] := NDSolve[{func2[r, u], z[0] == 1, z'[0] == 0}, z, {x, 0, 2}]

sol2[2, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]